# Javascript in php refresh page after dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I have the below php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['prano'])) {
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
    mysql_select_db('aplikacioni');
    $mbajtesi = $_SESSION['mbajtes'];

    for ($i=1; $i<=$mbajtesi; $i++) { 
        if (empty($notat[$i])) {
            $emp = "emp";
        }
    }

    if ($emp == "emp") {
        echo ("<script language = 'javascript'> window.alert('Something!!!');window.location.href='Snotat.php';</script>");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Now, this code means: When I press the button named 'prano' then displayed a table with input values.The user must fulfill all values..If not then he gets a message...
 So I don't want after the dialog message to disappear the table [remember the table appear when press button 'prano']...just I want to appear a dialog message without disappear the table..I've tried location.reload() but not work..any idea?

Comment: Are you ok there? Don't bang your head just yet.. People are coming to help.. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. Can you check your `$_SESSION['mbajtes']` & confirm that, `session_start();` line is exist in top of your page?

Comment: Learn my question again and you will understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't need to reload the page. You should use javascript/jQuery to insert an element to the body (for example) with that message.

Example:

```
<?php if ($emp == "emp") { ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('body').prepend('<div>Your message Here</div>);
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Remember to add jQuery to your header or footer.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```